# Researching into the nuts and bolts of displaying ESRI Grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis-2, esri-grid-format

I am trying to load an Arc/Info Binary Grid into QGIS 2.2.0 Valmiera installed in OS Windows 8.0. As far as I know, I only need to load the "w001001.adf" file contained in the "altitud" folder while keeping all other files there (Fig. 1), to see the raster and be able to work with it. There is no files names "altitud" to be loaded (as in ArcMap), and I have to load the "w001001.adf", which appears under the very same name in the layers toolbar (Fig. 2).

Conversely, when using ArcMap, we start adding the same raster data from the very same folder, and only one file with the name of the layer (altitud) appears (Fig. 3). All other files (dblbnd.adf, hdr.adf, prj.adf, sta.adf, w001001.adf, and w001001x.adf) are not displayed. One only needs to double click on the "altitud" file to load it, and this layer (and others) is displayed under the same name in ArcMap (Fig. 4).

At this point my questions are:

1) Why does QGIS behave somewhat differently from ArcMap in this respect?

2) Is there a way to load and see raster files in QGIS in the same was as in ArcMap, getting to see the actual layer names in the layers toolbar?

[image: Fig. 1. GRID directory containing associated files under QGIS]
[image: Fig. 2. "altitud" raster loaded into QGIS]
[image: Fig. 3. GRID directory containing associated files under ArcMap]
[image: Fig. 4. "altitud" layer loaded into ArcMap along with several others]

Comment: You're talking about an ArcGIS data format - not an 'open' format - so the *best* way would be to export the GRIDs as geoTIFF's or another georeferenced raster layer... I think...?